# Using client-go to `kubectl apply` against the Kubernetes API directly with multiple types in a single YAML file

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, client-go

I'm using https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go and all works well.

I have a manifest (YAML) for the official Kubernetes Dashboard: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

I want to mimic `kubectl apply` of this manifest in Go code, using client-go.

I understand that I need to do some (un)marshalling of the YAML bytes into the correct API types defined in package: https://github.com/kubernetes/api

I have successfully `Create`ed single API types to my cluster, **but how do I do this for a manifest that contains a list of types that are not the same**? Is there a resource `kind: List*` that supports these different types?

My current workaround is to split the YAML file using `csplit` with --- as the delimiter

```sh
csplit /path/to/recommended.yaml /---/ '{*}' --prefix='dashboard.' --suffix-format='%03d.yaml'
```

Next, I loop over the new (14) parts that were created, read their bytes, switch on the type of the object returned by the UniversalDeserializer's decoder and call the correct API methods using my k8s clientset.

I would like to do this to programmatically to make updates to any new versions of the dashboard into my cluster. I will also need to do this for the Metrics Server and many other resources. The alternative (maybe simpler) method is to ship my code with kubectl installed to the container image and directly call `kubectl apply -f -`; but that means I also need to write the kube config to disk or maybe pass it inline so that kubectl can use it.

I found this issue to be helpful: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/193
The decoder lives here: https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/tree/master/pkg/runtime/serializer

It's exposed in client-go here: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/scheme/register.go#L69

I've also taken a look at the RunConvert method that is used by kubectl: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/convert/convert.go#L139 and assume that I can provide my own [genericclioptions.IOStreams](https://github.com/kubernetes/cli-runtime/blob/master/pkg/genericclioptions/io_options.go#L27) to get the output?

[It looks like RunConvert is on a deprecation path](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/convert/convert.go#L141-L145)

I've also looked at other questions tagged [client-go] but most use old examples or use a YAML file with a single `kind` defined, and the API has changed since.

Edit: Because I need to do this for more than one cluster and am creating clusters programmatically (AWS EKS API + CloudFormation/[eksctl](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl)), I would like to minimize the overhead of creating `ServiceAccount`s across many cluster contexts, across many AWS accounts. Ideally, the only authentication step involved in creating my clientset is using [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) to get a token using cluster data (name, region, CA cert, etc). There hasn't been a release of aws-iam-authenticator for a while, but the contents of `master` allow for the use of a third-party role cross-account role and external ID to be passed. IMO, this is cleaner than using a `ServiceAccount` (and [IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html)) because there are other AWS services the application (the backend API which creates and applies add-ons to these clusters) needs to interact with.

Edit: I have recently found https://github.com/ericchiang/k8s. It's definitely simpler to use than client-go, at a high-level, but doesn't support this behavior.

Comment: Instead of writing kube config to container's disk try using service account
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

Comment: Why don't you just read the content of YAML file and split by `^---$` in your code?

Comment: @Shawyeok Because that still requires me to know what types are in the file. There is no way to get the type dynamically without testing against several expected types (Kubernetes objects), and if the expected type is not present then the object will not be applied to the cluster (which leads to even more problems). This would also result in having to write a lot of code for a single component which does not scale for several components. Beyond decoding is calling the correct API method to apply the object to a cluster.

Comment: @Simon Hi, Is there any solution? I'd like to deploy ServiceMesh `linkerd2` use client-go and the idea like you said mimic `kubectl apply -f -`. Should we use https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/596d7b0ffffd963af1b995fea599ad49d9b2a046/pkg/cmd/apply/apply.go#L161and do not need to manually split resource by their Kind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you've figured out how to deserialize YAML files into Kubernetes `runtime.Object`s, but the problem is dynamically deploying a `runtime.Object` without writing special code for each Kind.

`kubectl` achieves this by interacting with the [REST API](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/rest) directly. Specifically, via [resource.Helper](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/resource#Helper).

In my code, I have something like:

```
import (
    meta "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/meta"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema"
    "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/resource"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/restmapper"
)

func createObject(kubeClientset kubernetes.Interface, restConfig rest.Config, obj runtime.Object) (runtime.Object, error) {
    // Create a REST mapper that tracks information about the available resources in the cluster.
    groupResources, err := restmapper.GetAPIGroupResources(kubeClientset.Discovery())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    rm := restmapper.NewDiscoveryRESTMapper(groupResources)

    // Get some metadata needed to make the REST request.
    gvk := obj.GetObjectKind().GroupVersionKind()
    gk := schema.GroupKind{Group: gvk.Group, Kind: gvk.Kind}
    mapping, err := rm.RESTMapping(gk, gvk.Version)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    namespace, err := meta.NewAccessor().Namespace(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create a client specifically for creating the object.
    restClient, err := newRestClient(restConfig, mapping.GroupVersionKind.GroupVersion())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Use the REST helper to create the object in the "default" namespace.
    restHelper := resource.NewHelper(restClient, mapping)
    return restHelper.Create(namespace, false, obj)
}

func newRestClient(restConfig rest.Config, gv schema.GroupVersion) (rest.Interface, error) {
    restConfig.ContentConfig = resource.UnstructuredPlusDefaultContentConfig()
    restConfig.GroupVersion = &gv
    if len(gv.Group) == 0 {
        restConfig.APIPath = "/api"
    } else {
        restConfig.APIPath = "/apis"
    }

    return rest.RESTClientFor(&restConfig)
}
```

Comment: Hello Kevin, thank you for your answer! I haven't had a chance to get around to trying this, but I wasn't aware of `package restmapper` and this looks very promising. Accepting the answer for now, but will revisit it soon.

Comment: can you please provide a full example of this [all imports and so on]?

Comment: I was able to reach a point but I'm having this issue no kind "CustomResourceDefinition" is registered for version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100" --- trying to apply a crds file

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working in one of my projects. I had to use much of the source code from `kubectl`'s apply command to get it working correctly.

https://github.com/billiford/go-clouddriver/blob/master/pkg/kubernetes/client.go#L63

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar for testing purposes using [terratest](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/k8s#KubectlApply) - that is, I apply a yaml and then make some assertions about what is supposed to happen. This library specifically for testing, so I wouldn't recommend using it directly, but they use the simple approach - ship their code with kubectl and just [call the kubectl command](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/v0.46.8/modules/k8s/kubectl.go#L37).

If you're running the command outside of the cluster, you can use a kubeconfig - why don't you want to include the kubeconfig in a docker image?

If you're running it inside the cluster - use a service-account that has the relevant permissions through a role/clusterrole and rolebinding.